# jQuery drag and drop position error

Tags: jquery, draggable, positioning

Recently I have come to a dead end with the drag and drop on jQuery.

I have some div elements inside of a div container, all of this elements
are positioned using top and left css attributes. Some of this elements
must remain hidden (css display:none) and when a specific event triggers,
some of the hidden elements must be displayed. So far we are good, because
even though the elements were hidden, when they are shown they are located
on their correct spots with the top and left they were given. The problem 
starts when one of this previously hidden elements are dragged to be positioned
to some other place; for some odd reason when the drag starts, the element 
instead of stick to the cursor position, it goes like 300px below the cursor
and 200px to the left. Why is this happening, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing some code...

Comment: Do you have an example of your source HTML/CSS/JS for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used draggable objects yet, but the website says...

> To manipulate the position of a draggable during drag, you can either use a wrapper as the draggable helper and position the wrapped element with absolute positioning, or you can correct internal values like so:

```
$(this).data('draggable').offset.click.top -= x
```

You can also apply a style to the `.ui-draggable-dragging` class, but that's only a band-aid.